# What's a good way to create an "agree to terms" checkbox in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony

I have a form that has an "I have read and agree to the terms of service" checkbox on it. The box must be checked in order for the form to be considered valid, but there's no reason to save that value to the database, of course, and there's no reason to add an attribute to the Entity.

What's a good way to implement this kind of functionality in Symfony2 such that the form won't be considered valid unless the box is checked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [symfony docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#creating-form-classes):

> When mapping forms to objects, all fields are mapped. Any fields on the form that do not exist on the mapped object will cause an exception to be thrown.
>   In cases where you need extra fields in the form (for example: a "do you agree with these terms" checkbox) that will not be mapped to the underlying object, you need to set the property_path option to false:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('task');
    $builder->add('dueDate', null, array('property_path' => false));
}
```

> The field data can be accessed in a controller with:

```
$form->get('dueDate')->getData();
```

Comment: Symfony 2.4: it's now `'mapped' => false`

Answer (score 5):

This question is quite old and Symfony has updated this a lot. For Symfony 3.x you can do something like:

```
$builder->add('terms', CheckboxType::class, [
    'mapped' => false,
    'constraints' => new IsTrue(),
]);
```

Comment: This is the simplest way to deal with it.

Comment: This works only for cases when this field is mandatory.